# How can I use non ASCII file names in a zipped file and extract them using ZipFile in Python 2.4?

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-zipfile

I have a file öl_och_ål_är_gott.txt inside a zip archive named öl_och_ål_är_gott.zip. The archive isn't created using zipfile. It could come from any software capable of creating a zip archive.

```
src = open(file_path, "rb" )
zip_file = ZipFile(src)
for info in zip_file.infolist():
    print info.filename
    ...
```

prints out:

```
”l_och_†l_„r_gott.txt
```

How can I force zipfile to represent the name as I want it to be represented?

Answer (score 1):

As the docs state, there is no official file name encoding for ZIP files. If you have Unicode file names (as in your case), you must convert them to byte strings in your desired encoding before passing them.

[DOCS](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write)

Though I don't know why it doesn't work for you.

```
>>> src = open('/Desktop/test.zip', 'rb')
>>> zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(src)
>>> for info in zip_file.infolist():
...     print info.filename
... 
öl_och_ål_är_gott
```

On my Ubuntu box.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the archive wasn't created using zipfile. The archive comes from an arbitrary source.

Comment: In this case, I created the file myself without using `zipfile`. And that shouldn't matter. Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: I'm on Windows, but the archive could just as easily be created on a Linux or Mac machine. At least I want to be able to handle those cases.

Comment: I don't understand, I have no power over whether the creator of the zip archive has converted the file name to a byte string before creating the archive or not. The part of the docs you link to refer to the write method if I'm not mistaken. I only try to extract the data not compress.

Comment: Then you will need to decode the name from whatever encoding it is in. It looks like there's no reliable way to tell, but as a hint (from the docs): "WinZip interprets all file names as encoded in CP437, also known as DOS Latin." So try `info.filename.decode("cp437")`.

Comment: Yup, encoding that filename as cp437, then decoding with cp1252 gives the same result. Evidently Ubuntu's zip program uses an encoding that Python's expecting, while that on Windows doesn't. Welcome to the joys of character encoding, background is at: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @Thomas K: Thanks. Yes, that seems to be the way to go. Maybe I can minimize errors by just assuming that the encoding is CP437 ?

Comment: @MdaG: Well, it looks like that will work for files created in Winzip, but it might lead to similar problems with zip files from other sources (like Ubuntu). If the files you're handling will mostly be from Windows, you could assume cp437. Otherwise, you'll have to work out some way of making the program guess where each file comes from.

Comment: @Thomas K: Yes, I'm looking at the Zip File Format spec (http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) to see if I can use some bit in one of the fields to get the program to make an adequately good guess.

Comment: @MdaG: It might also be worth looking at the source of existing unzip utilities/libraries to see how they handle it.